Use Asyncio within a Loop
I have created a program that contains two main async functions that I run with asyncio:

get_all_group_members(): takes a list of Entra ID group IDs and returns a list of members of that group by using the Microsoft Graph API (using a function in another script)
get_user_name(): takes a list of users who have access to an Azure resource and gets the display name for the user using the Microsoft Graph API

EDIT: The library I am using/calling with my async functions is msgraph-sdk, the Microsoft Graph API library for Python.
If I run my program once, with one list of Entra ID groups and one list of Azure resource users, everything works just fine, I get the results I expect from the Graph API. However, if I then put my code into a loop that performs the same actions for multiple lists of groups and multiple lists of Azure resource users, it will fail only on the second iteration of the loop with error Event loop is closed. I get this error on the second iteration of the loop no matter which methodology I use with asyncio.
I want to know how I can perform separate Graph API async calls with asyncio and get the second loop of API calls to work. I need to be able to loop through a list of resources/groups and get data for all of them, not just run one group/list at a time.
What I've tried (none of these work for me):

Using asyncio.gather() and then asyncio.run()

async def get_all_group_members():
    memberListAll = []
    for group in groupList:
        results = await gq.get_group_user(group['GroupID'], graphServiceClient)
        memberDict = {"GroupName":group["GroupName"], "GroupID":group["GroupID"], "MemberList":results}
        memberListAll.append(memberDict)
    return memberListAll

# This function will get the display name for an Entra ID user based on the object ID for that account
async def get_user_name():
    ownerUsernameList = []
    for owner in ownersList:
        if owner['principalType'] == 'User':
            results = await gq.get_user_by_id(userID=owner['principalID'],graphServiceClient=graphServiceClient)
            ownerUsernameList.append(results)
    return ownerUsernameList

async def run_async_functions():
    groupResults, usernameResults = await asyncio.gather(get_all_group_members(), get_user_name())
    return groupResults, usernameResults

groupResults, usernameResults = asyncio.run(run_async_functions())


Creating my own Loop, opening the Loop, using the Loop, then closing the Loop. On the second iteration of the processing for my lists/calling the Graph API, my Loop will say it's open yet I'll still get the above error when it runs the async functions.

asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
newLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
isOpen = asyncio.get_event_loop().is_closed()
print("Is the loop open? ", not isOpen)
    >>>> Is the loop open? True

async def get_all_group_members():
    memberListAll = []
    for group in groupList:
        results = await gq.get_group_user(group['GroupID'], graphServiceClient) # Calls function from other script I wrote
        memberDict = {"GroupName":group["GroupName"], "GroupID":group["GroupID"], "MemberList":results}
        memberListAll.append(memberDict)
    return memberListAll
        
async def get_user_name():
    ownerUsernameList = []
    for owner in ownersList:
        if owner['principalType'] == 'User':
            results = await gq.get_user_by_id(userID=owner['principalID'],graphServiceClient=graphServiceClient)
            ownerUsernameList.append(results)
    return ownerUsernameList
        
# This function calls both of the above async functions so that we can have one function for asyncio to run
async def run_async_functions():
    groupResults = await get_all_group_members()
    usernameResults = await get_user_name()
    return groupResults, usernameResults

groupResults, usernameResults = newLoop.run_until_complete(run_async_functions())

newLoop.close()
isClosed = asyncio.get_event_loop().is_closed()
print("Is the loop closed? ", str(isClosed))
    >>>> Is the loop closed? True


Creating a separate loop for the first async function, closing that loop, then creating a second Loop for the second async function. Yet I still get a failure with the same error, but only on the second iteration of my script when it's processing the second list of groups/users.

async def get_all_group_members():
    memberListAll = []
    for group in groupList:
        results = await gq.get_group_user(group['GroupID'], graphServiceClient)
        memberDict = {"GroupName":group["GroupName"], "GroupID":group["GroupID"], "MemberList":results}
        memberListAll.append(memberDict)
    return memberListAll
        
async def get_user_name():
    ownerUsernameList = []
    for owner in ownersList:
        if owner['principalType'] == 'User':
            results = await gq.get_user_by_id(userID=owner['principalID'],graphServiceClient=graphServiceClient)
            ownerUsernameList.append(results)
    return ownerUsernameList
    
groupLoop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(groupLoop)
isOpen = asyncio.get_event_loop().is_closed()
print("Is the loop open? ", not isOpen)
    >>>> Is the loop open? True

groupResults = groupLoop.run_until_complete(get_all_group_members())

groupLoop.close()
isClosed = asyncio.get_event_loop().is_closed()
print("Is the loop closed? ", str(isClosed))
    >>>> Is the loop closed? True

usernameLoop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(usernameLoop)
isOpen = asyncio.get_event_loop().is_closed()
print("Is the loop open? ", not isOpen)
    >>>> Is the loop open? True

usernameResults = usernameLoop.run_until_complete(get_user_name())

usernameLoop.close()
isClosed = asyncio.get_event_loop().is_closed()
print("Is the loop closed? ", str(isClosed))
    >>>> Is the loop closed? True

So how do I successfully get these async functions to work and not error out on the second iteration of my program when I try to process the second list of groups and users? Why, even though I specifically open a loop and it says it is open, do I get an "event loop is closed" error?

You should make clear the python library you are using. I think I guessed the right one, but not 100% sure.

The issue appears related to the library you are using and how it recommends setting up your client objects (graphServiceClient in your case). It suggests creating clients at module import time. eg.
client = ...

async def some_function():
    return await client.do_something()

asyncio.run(some_function())

The problem with this approach is that the client embeds the asyncio loop that was around when it was created. So when it is run on a new event loop, it still tries to use the old (closed) event loop. asyncio.run() and your other approaches all create a new event loop per run, and so are guarenteed to fail on the second run.
The suggested solution is to create the client fresh, each time, inside an async function. By creating the client inside the async function you force client to be linked to the current executing event loop.
A basic structure that you could use to modify your code would be to use the contextvars module. It will allow you to get each function to get the client that is local to its event loop with a minimum of alteration to your current code.
import asyncio
import contextvars
import random

client = contextvars.ContextVar('client')

async def job():
    print(f'{client.get()=}')

async def main():
    client.set(random.random())
    await job()

asyncio.run(main())
asyncio.run(main())

Will print something like:
client.get()=0.8650939974300063
client.get()=0.20164744752604813

For more details see: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/issues/366

I really appreciate you responding so quickly. I think I already had by Graph Service Client connection creation set up in the way you mentioned, but was still not getting anything on that second loop. However, that thread you shared was incredibly helpful and got me to the solution! This answer is what finally fixed my issue.
